# Proxycommand and ncat not work with dynamic port fwd

Tags: ssh

Im trying to connect to some devices from a Centos7 server,  via a jump machine using dynamic port fwd.

I have this .ssh/config:

```
*Host jump
        TCPKeepAlive yes
        ServerAliveInterval 1200
        HostName x.x.x.x
        DynamicForward 1080
Host hl*
        ProxyCommand nc -x 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p*

Then I set up the dynamic port fwd in the jump machine:

*[root@host ~]#ssh -fN user@jump* 

Then when i try the ssh to the final device I get this error:

*[root@host ~]#ssh user@hl4man1 -vv
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 10: Applying options for hl*
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec nc -x 127.0.0.1:1080 hl4man1 22
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
**Ncat: Could not resolve hostname "hl4man1": Name or service not known. QUITTING.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host**
[root@host ~]#*
```

If I do a static port forwarding it works fine.

Any idea?

Rgds / Luis

Comment: _'Could not resolve hostname "hl4man1"'_

Answer (score 0):

You can't proxy to a host which your man-in-the middle can't find.

```
Ncat: Could not resolve hostname "hl4man1": Name or service not known. QUITTING.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Try connecting to a host that exists insofar as the proxy host can find?

Put another way, you can't ask Bob to get something from Larry's house if Bob doesn't know where Larry lives.

Comment: Hi, hl4man1 is known by the jump host. I can ssh user@hl4man1 from the jump host.

Comment: Is this because the host is defined in the `ssh` config on the jump host?  Because `nc` doesn't read that.

Comment: The jump host uses DNS in the remote network to access all the nodes, the name of nodes in which im interested in start with hl*.